# What do the Borg eat?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg, food

We know Seven of Nine eats after she was severed from the collective. We know the Borg drones recharge/sleep in individual docking stations. Do the Borg drones eat? If so, what do they eat, and how is it ingested?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the TNG episode ["I, Borg"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Borg), Hugh was fed by absorbing energy through a port in his arm.  La Forge had to install a matching coupling in the wall of Hugh's cell.  The Borg implants convert energy into glucose and whatever nutrients the Borg's organic side needs to keep functioning.

> ***[Crusher](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/223.htm) :*** The Borg don't ingest food. Their implants can synthesise any organic molecules the biological tissues require. What
>   they need is energy.

Comment: Seven needed to eat because many of her implants were removed after she was separated from the Collective.

Answer (score -1):

Voyager S6 E2 -- "Survival Instinct" -- has a scene of Seven and other drones gathered around a fire, eating meat that starts to trigger memories in each of their lives before the Borg.

Like Proust's Remembrance. The primal act of eating floods in an existential consciousness and a will to narration, of epic proportions.

I would submit that eating is not only not Borg, but perhaps even antithetical to what is Borg. Regeneration in alcoves or otherwise presumably has some biological component -- perhaps nutrition is IV'd in in some way?

Comment: Hi there. There is part of an answer in here, though mostly commentary; I suggest you [edit] your post to clarify whether Borg's are actually never seen eating, or take a stand against it, stuff like this. This would make for a better answer.

Comment: @Vijay Pattisapu - An anonymous user has attempted to edit this answer. If that person is you, you should use the same account you used to post this answer to edit it; that  way, you won't need to submit the edit for approval by other users for the edit to go through. If you can no longer access your previous account for some reason, you can merge your new account with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).