# What does Moya eat?

Tags: farscape

Moya, the living ship from Farscape, is described as a biomechanoid. I guess that should categorize her as a cyborg, since she is composed of both organic and robotic parts.

Naturally, she would need some source of energy. Was it ever revealed if the energy source was technological, organic or possibly both? What fuels Moya's systems? Is it solar power, nuclear fusion, antimatter reactor, some other phlebotinum...? What does sustain her organic part? Does the mechanical part generate necessary nutrients ([like the Borg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13656/what-do-the-borg-eat)) or does she actually eat? What kind of a meal does appear on a Leviathan menu?

Comment: Perhaps the DRDs catch rats and feed them to her/it.

Comment: I see nothing on the [Leviathan](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Leviathan) wikia page, but I feel certain it did come up at least once.  Maybe it was solar power and referenced in [Crackers Don't Matter](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Crackers_Don%27t_Matter)?

Comment: I thought it's been mentioned in at least one episode. I'm not really sure though. But even if she's fed by the artifical components, the species should be able to 'eat' somehow.

Comment: First thing came to mind for me, upon reading your question, was perhaps some biological parallel to the bussard collectors on Federation ships in Star Trek, scooping up interstellar matter for consumption.

Comment: Perhaps, and this is speculation bordering on fan-fiction, Leviathans have a larval stage which does all the eating they need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**At no point is Moya ever seen eating on camera. We must infer, as an organism that lives its entire life in space, it would make sense for her species to subsist off of whatever can be found between stars. I would think new star systems and planetary bodies would be the equivalent of watering holes she would be able to lay over near and recharge.**

**As such, she should be able to subsist off of the radiation of stars including high energy particles and cosmic rays, x-rays and gamma rays, solar particles and perhaps even hydrogen gas from large gas giants, which are shrouded in such clouds. She might replenish her mass by passing through dust clouds with a high mineral content.**

That said:

- She does not appear to use solar energy as a primary food source, though it is not said that she couldn't or didn't
- nor is she seen scooping gas from gas giants for raw materials to repair herself or to replace mass.
- This also does not mean she couldn't or didn't only that **we didn't see it**. No one tuned in to Farscape to watch a Leviathan eat.

She apparently does have a need for a particular type of [unobtainium](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Unobtainium) known as **"iriscentent fluid"** which is used by her power plant and life sustaining systems. It can be found on most sophisticated commerce planets and considered very expensive.

> In the premiere episode Rygel tries to sell the Hurlian Stone set into a ring he owned. He tried to sell the ring to a green alien with a bottom jaw that split apart. He wanted 35 barrels of iriscentent fluid, but the alien offered him 20 for it. ("Farscape Premiere")

The material, iriscentent fluid, is mentioned only in passing in episodes where the crew are stopping on commerce planets to resupply. Since she does not appear to need much material to repair or restore herself, she must have a super-efficient bio-mechanical repair system, able to utilize any and all mass on board to repair or replace systems.

> After escaping the Peacekeepers, Moya was able to locate this [small Commerce Planet](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Commerce_Planet_01) in the Uncharted Territories. The Moya's crew was hoping to find supplies in order to make repairs to Moya. Rygel, Zhaan, and Ka D'Argo headed down to the planet and Rygel bartered with a shop owner for barrels of iriscentent fluid.

Since the Leviathans are a constructed race created by the [Builders](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Builder), they may be able to survive on any number of other materials unknown to us. The Builders possessed nearly godlike powers and were capable of living unaided in space in non-corporeal bodies.

> The Builders are an ancient and powerful race and are considered by Leviathans to be gods. In fact, the Builders originally constructed Leviathans as ordinary biomechanical ships, only later giving them sentience (souls) and the ability to reproduce on their own.

---

The source for this very hard to find information was a book called "[Investigating Farscape: Uncharted Territories of Sex and Science Fiction](http://books.google.com/books?id=jJD4z3mEHi8C&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=%22iriscentent%20fluid%22&source=bl&ots=0U2-pIt0Sh&sig=TRHAj8u-hyJdR6uThr1Ymv7auQ8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lz_-T_2_JcfErQHVju2LCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22iriscentent%20fluid%22&f=false)" where they list in their glossary of terms, the material called "iriscentent fluid."

The entry is listed as such:

> **iriscentent fluid:** *noun* - a fluid Moya uses for fuel, and necessary for her functioning.

Comment: Excellent answer and well researched!

Answer (score 0):

Considering they never mention Moya or Talyn getting hungry and the fact that they are artificially created I'm wondering if maybe they are fully self sustaining and in fact don't need sustenance unless they are injured enough that they need external support such as during the premiere she was badly damaged so she needed some of her fluids replaced like if we bled out we would need a blood donor.

Comment: Anything that expends energy (e.g. healing/repair, growth, movement, etc.) needs energy intake. There are no such things as perpetual motion machines, even if 100% efficiency could be achieved. The fact that Moya has to not only sustain herself and provide a comfortable oxygen environment and artificial gravity for her pilot, DRDs, and crew, as well as starburst, power internal and external machinery, reproduce, haul cargo, etc. means that she has to absorb energy from somewhere. You can't get something from nothing.

Answer (score -1):

On the movie moya crash landed on a planets ocean and she was absorbing the water and minerals in it to heal I think as she is in space there are holes that are unseen that sucks space debris in and filters it absorbing only whats she needs and lets the rest go her outer hull looks metallic so mabe she absorbs solar energy to help with maintaining energy it must take time to recharge for a star burst so she might suck in debris to feed on to make energy to recharge are mabe she has a internal stomach and there's a room near it were she sheads off layers of organic matireal and it drops in her stomach it whould be like eating hershelf but at the same time it shouldn't it whould be like a snake shedding and eating its shredded skin and I think moya moves at the sides she has a sucking system to move forword and flexes her body slowly there has to be some way she thrusts hershelf to move and I think they should have had a growing room like a green house so they can grow food and healing plants zhann chould have healed hershelf in that room moya should of had a organic energy bio field to protected but the stronger the weapon the weaker it will get and can't stare burst if its up well just had to get this off my mind Ty and the drds some of them should of had wings are some spider like with webs to heal and catch intruders

Comment: Please write in sentences and paragraphs.

Answer (score -4):

Does she not feed from the power of whichever local star she drew near?

Comment: Can you cite an episode or other source where this is stated?